# Vosk не видит модель после конвертации в exe

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe, vosk

Написал голосового ассистента на python c библиотекой vosk, и решил конвертировать в exe файл, но при запуске exe файла выскакивает эта ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 95, in <module>
    File "vosk\__init__.py", line 57, in __init__
    raise Exception("Failed to create a model")
Exception: Failed to create a model
```

Если код не конвертировать то все работает нормально и никаких ошибок. Путь до модели указан верно я проверял несколько раз. Конвертировал при помощи auto-py-to-exe все зависимости указаны верно.

Comment: Показывайте свой код, как собирали exe, какие команды. По одной ошибке не понятно что у вас не так.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибку исправил просто указав полный путь до модели

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].

Comment: А как же это утверждение "Путь до модели указан верно я проверял несколько раз."?